# Decompile or analyse injected /usr/bin/cat

Tags: binary-analysis, decompilation, linux, debuggers, binary

I'm trying to decompile or analyse an injected Linux executable binary file **/usr/bin/cat** ,and find the injected code as a readable.

Need some tips as a beginner how to find the injection method if it's the right start.

Comment: Does this question help? https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/26386

Comment: Do you have access to the original binary e.g. from your Linux distribution, to compare it to? I’d also guess you could get Ghidra or similar to just decompile everything and find the code in there.